# Can't see the migrate list in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on my first Django Project and while learning about migrations I was to use this command to see the lists.

> **python3 manage.py migrate --list**

But instead of giving me the list it gives an error

```
usage: manage.py migrate [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS]
                     [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback] [--no-color]
                     [--noinput] [--database DATABASE] [--fake]
                     [--fake-initial] [--run-syncdb]
                     [app_label] [migration_name]


manage.py migrate: error: unrecognized arguments: --list
```

But even after that, When I am trying to migrate usinng this commannd

> **python3 manage.py migrate**

it gives no error.

The only issue arises when I am trying to use the list command.So any advice will be much helpful for me.Thanks.

P.S. I am using Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#showmigrations), you should use "showmigrations". It can be used with django-admin:

```
django-admin showmigrations
```

Or with manage.py

```
python manage.py showmigrations
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It worked.One thing only.The tutorial in which I saw it used --list.So was it for Python 2 or something?

Comment: @john400 from Django version 1.7 to 1.8 it changed, as you can see on the end of the section about "migrate" on the doc for 1.8 version
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#migrate-app-label-migrationname